# Remove darkcoin-qt

Tags: uninstall, bitcoin

How do I remove cleanly darkcoin-qt application (the wallet for darkcoin) ?
I tried "sudo apt-get remove darkcoin-qt" but it does not work ("unable to locate package...").

Comment: If you didn't install a deb or through `apt-get`, you can't remove it from `apt-get`.

Comment: OK, is there a way to remove it completely ?

Comment: Depends on how you installed it. Did you just extract files somewhere? Did you compile something?

Comment: I followed the guide: https://darkcointalk.org/threads/how-to-make-the-darkcoin-wallet-for-linux.214/  ; so yes I had to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you didn't run `sudo make install`, you can just remove the folder, and Darkcoin itself will be removed. If the program stores any configuration settings, you'll need to remove those yourself. They may be in `~/.darkcoin` or `~/.config/darkcoin` (or similarly-named folders).

To remove the build dependencies, run `sudo apt-get purge qt4-qmake libqt4-dev build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev libssl-dev libdb++-dev libminiupnpc-dev` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove`. If you know you use any of the build dependencies listed in other software, remove it from this list.